# I2C communication of pic16f1704 using xc8 compiler

Tags: c, pic

I am using a PIC16f1704 microcontroller and my compiler is xc8. I have been trying to obtain I2C communication of the controller with adress 0x00. My SCL pin is RC0 and SDA pin is RC1. I found that the built-in functions in xc8 compiler dosent work with pic16. I made the following code according to the datasheet. But I couldn't get SCL and SDA waveforms after compiling my code.

Please see if my code is correct and please let me know where did I went wrong.

```
#include<xc.h>
#pragma config FOSC=INTOSC, PLLEN=OFF, MCLRE=ON, WDTE=OFF
#pragma config LVP=OFF, CLKOUTEN=OFF
#define SCL     TRISC0
#define SDA     TRISC1
#define SCL_IN  RC0    
#define SDA_IN  RC1
void init()
{
    SDA = SCL = 1;
    SCL_IN = SDA_IN = 1;    //SDA & SCL at high state
}
void i2c_start(void)
{
    SDA = 1;             // i2c start bit sequence
    SCL = 1;
    _delay(10000);
    SDA = 0;
    SCL = 1;
    _delay(10000);
}
void i2c_stop(void)
{
    SDA = 0;             // i2c stop bit sequence
    _delay(10000);
    SCL = 1;
    _delay(1000);
    SDA = 1;
   _delay(10000);
}
void I2CWait()
{
    while ((SSPCON2 & 0x1F ) || ( SSPSTAT & 0x04 ) );
}

void main()
{
    OSCCONbits.SCS = 0x02; //set the SCS bits to select internal oscillator block
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0x0F; //set OSCCON IRCF
    BAUD1CONbits.BRG16=0;  //BRGH IS NOT VALID IN SYNCHRONOUS TRANSMISSION
    SPBRGH = 0X00;
    SPBRGL = 0X19;
    SLRCONC = 0xff;     //Slew rate IS LIMITED
    ANSELC = 0x00;      //Digital mode is selected
    SSPCLKPPS = 0x10;
    SSPDATPPS = 0X11;   //PPL for input pins
    RC0PPS = 0X10;
    RC1PPS = 0X11;      //PPL for output pins
    SSPCONbits.SSPM0=0;
    SSPCON1bits.SSPM1=0;
    SSPCON1bits.SSPM2=0;
    SSPCON1bits.SSPM3=1;    //selecting I2C master mode
    SSP1STATbits.SMP=1;    //SLEW RATE CONTROL
    SSP1STATbits.CKE=1;   //CLOCK EDGE SELECT BIT
    SPEN=1;
    ACKEN=1;
    SSPCON1=0X28;          //sync. serial port enable bit is set along with I2C mastermode
    SSPADD=0X27;           //calculated value
    GIE=1;
    PIE1=1;
    TXIE=1;
    init();
    SEN=1;               //start enable
    i2c_start();
    I2CWait();
    _delay(10000);
    SSPBUF=0X00;
    _delay(10000);
    PEN=1;                 //stop enable
    i2c_stop();
}
```

Also please see these kind of initialization is required for start condition.

```
void i2c_start(void)
{
    SDA = 1;             // i2c start bit sequence
    SCL = 1;
    _delay(10000);
    SDA = 0;
    SCL = 1;
    _delay(10000);
}
```

I think it is not necessary.When SEN(Start enable) bit is set  controller drives   SDA low and SCL remain high.

Answer (score 0):

You said :

> I think it is not necessary.When SEN(Start enable) bit is set
>   controller drives SDA low and SCL remain high.

You are right. But not only for the start condition but also for repeated start, stop, etc... You have never to control directly the pins SCL and SDA by yourself (even in your initialisation function, you have only to set the direction as input).

Example for the start condition :

```
void i2c_start(void)
{
SSPCON2.SEN = 1;//start condition generation
while(!PIR1.SSPIF);//wait until MSSP has finished
PIR1.SSPIF = 0;//clear the flag
}//at the exit of the function, start condition is complete
```

The term of "start condition enable" is not properly used by Microchip : It doesn't enable the start condition but it generates a start condition...

So you don't have to write the SCL and SDA pins by yourself, nor using a delay. You just have to write the correct bit for condition generation (SEN, RSEN, PEN) or the buffer (SSPBUF) then waiting on SSPIF bit for the operation to be completed.

Its the same way for generating the repeated start and stop conditions.

You will find complete informations for i2c master mode transmission at the page 318 of the datasheet.

Hope it will help you,
Regards.